# asynchronous SNMP query devices with RxPHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, snmp

I'd like to asynchronously query devices via SNMP and when result arrives store it in database.

```
$devices = ['192.168.10.11','192.168.10.21','192.168.10.22','192.168.10.23', ...];

function getSnmp($ip, $community, $oid) {
 $snmp = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $ip, $community);
  return $res = $snmp->get($oid);
}
```

now with foreach I can query devices but synchronously.

In RxPHP there is method `Promise\all(array $promisesOrValues)` https://github.com/reactphp/promise#all

How can I make promise from `getSnmp()` function to provide as `$promises` in `Promise\all()` ?

Comment: I'have the same problem. Have You solved it?

Comment: But I think that is better to use Observable instead of Promise. If Observable stucks, for some reason, You can break it and with Promise is problem in that case.